# How can I properly close pool in HikariCP?

Tags: jdbc, hikaricp

I use connection pool from HikariCP. HikariCP after every request takes connection to pool back, but ain't closing it, so I have idle connections in DB, which I have to close by the hand (for example).

How can I properly close pool after every request, because I don't need constant pools actively?

Here is my class which connects to DB:

```java
public class ReportRequester {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public List<List<Object>> request(String request) {
        return jdbcTemplate.execute((Connection connection) -> {
            List<List<Object>> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
            try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(request);
                 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

                ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    List<Object> row = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
                        row.add(rs.getObject(i));
                    }
                    objectList.add(row);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // обработка исключения
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log.info("Connection has been closed");
            return objectList;
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to use

```ini
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout= 60000,
```

but realised it doesn't close pool. How can I configure closing connection pool? I know it's not recommended, but unfortunately I need to.

I tried to use try-with-resources but it also didn't give my anything.

Comment: So you're using a pool but you don't want it to use the pool functionality. Why not just skip using and handle raw connections yourself?

Comment: Do you realise that the whole point of a connection pool is to keep the connection open, so it can be reused by the next request to `DataSource.getConnection`? That the pool keeps the connection open is the correct and intended behaviour. If you don't want that, then you shouldn't be using a connection pool, or you are not properly explaining/describing your problem.